# Serve compressed content XOR range: bytes with nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm serving static content using nginx. I'd like to support both [Range requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) and gzip compression.

Unfortunately, these two features are [not compatible](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,209738,209850) in nginx. Adding `gzip on;` to my config disables range requests.

Assuming I can't gzip everything, the next best option would be to enable gzip for all requests which lack a `Range:` header. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution would be to add these lines next to every "gzip on" in your configuration:

```
if ($http_range) {
   gzip off;
}
```

Even though "if" is evil, in this case alternatives are even worse. If there are any at all.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've posted my working nginx conf file [here](https://gist.github.com/danvk/1614c1f22251f959a92b). I also needed CORS support, which I had to put in `if` statements above the gzip one.

Comment: This wound up being pretty tricky. There's a bad interaction between the `Last-modified` header and range requests in Chrome, so I had to disable those, too. "if" in nginx has very strange behavior. I've updated the gist referenced in the previous comment.

Comment: Enabling gzip works on my server. But when I add your if-statement to disable it nginx gives me an error: "gzip directive is not allowed here". Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: I found my error. The gzip directive is only allowed within an if-condition if the if-condition is within a location block - not if it is directly within a server block.